# svg static image within the area of a polygon

Tags: google-maps-api-3

How do I get the svg image is static when I zoom in on the map, which always remains in the same place.

This is my [fiddle](https://fiddle.jshell.net/u14vyz64/)

If I use png images works , but it is not visually well for me and is not what i'm looking for.

Help is appreciated

Sorry for my english.

new [Fiddle](https://fiddle.jshell.net/u14vyz64/3/)

Comment: If you want the icon not to move when the map zooms, you need to set the anchor correctly.  Do you want the icon to stay the same size as well with respect to the polygon?

Comment: That's my idea. If I put anchor svg icon disappears and marker shows

Comment: I'm not sure what that means.  Please clarify in your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The anchor is expected to be a Point, not a LatLng.

The default-acnchor is the bottom-middle of the icon, as it seems you need to set it to the top-left, so it has to be:

```
new google.maps.Point(0,0)
```

When you want to have a scaled icon  based on the zoom you must calculate the scale-property and re-assign the icon to the marker.

The formula would be(assuming the scale-factor at zoom 12 is 1):

```
Math.pow(2,map.getZoom()-12)
```

```js
function initialize() {


  var mapOptions = {

    center: new google.maps.LatLng(-32.95041520, -60.66641804),
    zoom: 12,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.TERRAIN
  };

  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'),
    mapOptions);

  triangleCoords = [
    new google.maps.LatLng(-32.93831432, -60.69379806),
    new google.maps.LatLng(-32.96337859, -60.67860603),
    new google.maps.LatLng(-32.96352262, -60.66633224),
    new google.maps.LatLng(-32.95041520, -60.66641807)
  ];

  var bermudaTriangle = new google.maps.Polygon({
    paths: triangleCoords,
    IsInactivo: true


  });

  bermudaTriangle.setMap(map);

  var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
  var i;

  for (i = 0; i < triangleCoords.length; i++) {
    bounds.extend(triangleCoords[i]);
  }

  console.log(bounds.getCenter());

  centroPolygon = bounds.getCenter();


  var inactive = new google.maps.MVCObject();
  inactive.set('icon', {
    path: 'M27.314 4.686c-3.022-3.022-7.040-4.686-11.314-4.686s-8.292 1.664-11.314 4.686c-3.022 3.022-4.686 7.040-4.686 11.314s1.664 8.292 4.686 11.314c3.022 3.022 7.040 4.686 11.314 4.686s8.292-1.664 11.314-4.686c3.022-3.022 4.686-7.040 4.686-11.314s-1.664-8.292-4.686-11.314zM28 16c0 2.588-0.824 4.987-2.222 6.949l-16.727-16.727c1.962-1.399 4.361-2.222 6.949-2.222 6.617 0 12 5.383 12 12zM4 16c0-2.588 0.824-4.987 2.222-6.949l16.727 16.727c-1.962 1.399-4.361 2.222-6.949 2.222-6.617 0-12-5.383-12-12z',
    fillColor: '#FF5858',
    fillOpacity: 0.4,
    scale: 1,
    strokeColor: '#FF5858',
    strokeWeight: 1,
    //set the anchor to the top left corner of the svg
    anchor: new google.maps.Point(0, 0)


  });

  google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'zoom_changed', function() {
    inactive.get('icon').scale = Math.pow(2, this.getZoom() - 12);
    //tell the marker that the icon has changed
    inactive.notify('icon');
  });
  google.maps.event.trigger(map, 'zoom_changed');

  new google.maps.Marker({
    map: map,
    position: centroPolygon
  }).bindTo('icon', inactive, 'icon');
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize)
```

```css
      html,
      body,
      #map-canvas {
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0px;
        padding: 0px
      }
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3&.js"></script>
<div id="map-canvas"></div>
```